# Compiled R code is actually slower than pure R with JIT enabled

Tags: r, bytecode, jit, microbenchmark

From [Efficient R programming the byte compiler](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/7-4-the-byte-compiler.html) and [R docment r byte compiler](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/compiler/versions/3.5.2/topics/compile), I learnt that `cmpfun` can be used to compile a pure `R` function into byte code to speed and `enableJIT` can speed up by enabling `just-in-time` compilation.

So, I decided to do the benchmark just like [the first link](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/7-4-the-byte-compiler.html) myself using the following code:

```
library("compiler")
library("rbenchmark")

enableJIT(3)

my_mean = function(x) {
    total = 0
    n = length(x)
    for (each in x)
        total = total + each
    total / n
}

cmp_mean = cmpfun(my_mean, list(optimize = 3))

## Generate some data
x = rnorm(100000)
benchmark(my_mean(x), cmp_mean(x), mean(x), columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"), order = "relative", replications = 5000)
```

Unfortunately, the result is no where like what [the first link](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/7-4-the-byte-compiler.html) has shown. The performance of `my_mean` is even better than `cmp_mean`:

```
         test elapsed relative
3     mean(x)   1.468    1.000
1  my_mean(x)  35.402   24.116
2 cmp_mean(x)  36.817   25.080
```

I can't figure out what has happened.

Edit:

The `R` version on my computer is `3.5.2`.

The operating system `debian 9.8`. Every software on my computer is up-to-date with the stable source provided by `debian`.

`linux` kernel version `4.9.0-8-amd64`.

Eidt5:

I rewrote the scripts to test different combination of `optimize` and `JIT`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library("compiler")
library("microbenchmark")
library("rlist")

my_mean = function(x) {
    total = 0
    n = length(x)
    for (each in x)
    total = total + each
    total / n
}

do_cmpfun = function(f, f_name, optimization_level) {
    cmp_f = cmpfun(f, list(optimize = optimization_level))
    list(cmp_f, f_name, optimize = optimization_level)
}

do_benchmark = function(f, f_name, optimization_level, JIT_level, x) {
    result = summary(microbenchmark(f(x), times = 1000, unit = "us", control = list(warmup = 100)))
    data.frame(fun = f_name, optimize = optimization_level, JIT = JIT_level, mean = result$mean)
}

means = list(list(mean, "mean", optimize = -1), list(my_mean, "my_mean", optimize = -1))

for (optimization_level in 0:3)
    means = list.append(means, do_cmpfun(my_mean, "my_mean", optimization_level))

# Generate some data
x = rnorm(100000)

# Benchmark in different JIT levels
result = c()
for (JIT_level in 0:3) {
    enableJIT(JIT_level)

    for (f in means) {
    result = rbind(result, do_benchmark(f[[1]], f[[2]], f[[3]], JIT_level, x))
    }
}


# Sort result
sorted_result = result[order(result$mean), ]
rownames(sorted_result) = NULL

print("Unit = us, optimize = -1 means it is not processed by cmpfun")
print(sorted_result)
```

I ran `sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance` before running the R script and got this:

```
[1] "Unit = us, optimize = -1 means it is not processed by cmpfun"
       fun optimize JIT       mean
1     mean       -1   2   229.1841
2     mean       -1   1   229.3910
3     mean       -1   3   236.3680
4     mean       -1   0   252.9416
5  my_mean       -1   2  5242.0413
6  my_mean        3   0  5279.9710
7  my_mean        2   2  5297.5323
8  my_mean        2   1  5327.0324
9  my_mean       -1   1  5333.6941
10 my_mean        3   1  5336.4559
11 my_mean        2   0  5362.6644
12 my_mean        3   3  5410.1963
13 my_mean        2   3  5414.4616
14 my_mean       -1   3  5418.3823
15 my_mean        3   2  5437.3233
16 my_mean        1   2  9947.7897
17 my_mean        1   1 10101.6464
18 my_mean        1   3 10204.3253
19 my_mean        1   0 10323.0782
20 my_mean        0   0 26557.3808
21 my_mean        0   2 26728.5222
22 my_mean       -1   0 26901.4200
23 my_mean        0   3 26984.5200
24 my_mean        0   1 27060.6188
```

However, after I `update-alternative`d `libblas.so.3` and `liblapack.so.3` to the one provided by `openblas 0.2.19-3`, `my_mean` with `optimize = 3` and `JIT = 0` becomes the one that has the best performance (excluding `mean`):

```
[1] "Unit = us, optimize = -1 means it is not processed by cmpfun"
       fun optimize JIT       mean
1     mean       -1   0   228.9361
2     mean       -1   1   229.1223
3     mean       -1   2   233.9757
4     mean       -1   3   241.7835
5  my_mean        3   0  5246.8089
6  my_mean       -1   1  5261.3951
7  my_mean       -1   2  5330.6310
8  my_mean        2   3  5362.2055
9  my_mean        3   1  5400.9983
10 my_mean        2   0  5418.7674
11 my_mean        2   1  5460.8133
12 my_mean        3   3  5464.8280
13 my_mean       -1   3  5520.7021
14 my_mean        2   2  5591.7352
15 my_mean        3   2  5610.6446
16 my_mean        1   3 10244.2832
17 my_mean        1   0 10274.7504
18 my_mean        1   1 10311.6423
19 my_mean        1   2 10735.6449
20 my_mean        0   2 26904.1858
21 my_mean       -1   0 26961.0536
22 my_mean        0   0 27115.8191
23 my_mean        0   3 27538.7224
24 my_mean        0   1 28133.6159
```

Same with `mkl 2019.02-057`:

```
[1] "Unit = us, optimize = -1 means it is not processed by cmpfun"
       fun optimize JIT       mean
1     mean       -1   1   257.8620
2     mean       -1   0   263.3743
3     mean       -1   2   280.6906
4     mean       -1   3   291.8409
5  my_mean        2   0  5445.3252
6  my_mean        2   2  5462.4575
7  my_mean        3   3  5560.2931
8  my_mean       -1   1  5591.0089
9  my_mean        3   1  5645.3897
10 my_mean        3   0  5676.1714
11 my_mean        3   2  5707.7964
12 my_mean        2   3  5757.7887
13 my_mean       -1   3  5856.0215
14 my_mean       -1   2  5897.1735
15 my_mean        2   1  6363.1090
16 my_mean        1   2  9973.7666
17 my_mean        1   1 10557.8154
18 my_mean        1   0 10926.6103
19 my_mean        1   3 16030.0326
20 my_mean        0   0 27461.4078
21 my_mean        0   1 27939.7680
22 my_mean       -1   0 27985.4590
23 my_mean        0   3 30394.2772
24 my_mean        0   2 33768.5701
```

Comment: I also get that `my_mean()` and `cmp_mean()` seem to be in a virtual tie for all problem sizes. I can't replicate the graph in that link which shows that their `cmp_mean` is dramatically better. Not sure when that was written. Perhaps there has been an improvement in the R interpreter since then and that now the optimizations which `cmpfun()` does are done automatically? Alternatively, a glance at the table of contents shows something about changing which BLAS R uses. Perhaps their results are when a non-default BLAS is used? It is a good question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I did the experiment both with and without `enableJIT` and also with `microbenchmark` rather than `benchmark`, and in no case does `cmpfun` seem to help but instead seems to (very slightly) hurt.

Comment: Since [3.4](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) JIT is  enabled by default. Maybe it has something to do with that (ie, book is outdated). You can try confirming that by testing on 3.3, 3.4, 3.5

Comment: You can test different versions of r with rstudio.cloud pretty easily. In I just tested with R3.1, but `cmp_mean` is about 3 times faster than `my_mean`.

Comment: The differences are very small and likely not significant.

Comment: @PoGibas It seems that `my_mean` is faster than `cmp_mean` when `JIT = 2` is the case since `3.3.3`. I did the benchmark on `rstudio.cloud`.

Comment: However, this is not true in `3.4.4`.

Answer (score 5):

While I haven't figured out why the JIT compiling isn't speeding up your code, we can speed up the same function by compiling it using the [Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-sugar) package.

Doing so gives the following results (where mean_cpp is the function written and compiled using Rcpp:

```
         test elapsed relative
4 mean_cpp(x)    0.67    1.000
3     mean(x)    1.00    1.493
1  my_mean(x)   14.00   20.896
2 cmp_mean(x)   14.50   21.642
```

The code to generate this function is given below.

```
library("compiler")
library("rbenchmark")
library("Rcpp")


enableJIT(3)

my_mean = function(x) {
  total = 0
  n = length(x)
  for (each in x)
    total = total + each
  total / n
}

cmp_mean = cmpfun(my_mean, list(optimize = 3))


#we can also write this same function using the Rcpp package
cppFunction('double mean_cpp(NumericVector x) {
  double total = 0;
  int n = x.size();
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total / n;
}')


#run once to compile
mean_cpp(c(1))


## Generate some data
x = rnorm(100000)
benchmark(my_mean(x), cmp_mean(x), mean(x), mean_cpp(x),
          columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"),
          order = "relative", replications = 5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used both `enableJIT(3)` and `cmpfun`.
Try `enableJIT(0)` and the difference comes up. This is what I get

```
         test elapsed relative
3     mean(x)    1.06    1.000
2 cmp_mean(x)   13.83   13.047
1  my_mean(x)  161.58  152.434
```

On running this code:

```
library("compiler")
library("rbenchmark")

enableJIT(0)

my_mean = function(x) {
    total = 0
    n = length(x)
    for (each in x)
        total = total + each
    total / n
}

cmp_mean = cmpfun(my_mean, list(optimize = 3))

## Generate some data
x = rnorm(100000)
benchmark(my_mean(x), cmp_mean(x), mean(x), columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"), order = "relative", replications = 5000)
```

`enableJIT` is by default activated in R, and not setting it to zero I get:

```
         test elapsed relative
3     mean(x)    1.11    1.000
1  my_mean(x)   14.28   12.865
2 cmp_mean(x)   14.50   13.063
```